Capacitance Formula derivation
Can anyone help me with how this formula came in the first place (marked in red)? I am not able to understand the denominator term.
This is with reference to Double Pulse Test taken from the book : Characterization of Wide Bandgap Power Semiconductor Devices by
Fei (Fred) Wang, Zheyu Zhang, and Edward A. Jones

DPT circuit for reference where Bulk caps = Cbulk.


Context? We need a schematic to give meaning to those symbols.

@Neil_UK updated. thanks

Are you familiar with the equations for energy in a capacitor and inductor?

Yes @TimWilliams 1/2CV^2 > 1/2 LI^2  I get it

Not quite; what is the energy in the capacitor before and after a pulse? And the corresponding voltage?

@Andr7 Capacitor energy: $E_{\text{C}}=\frac12,C,V{\text{C}}^2$. Take the differential: $\text{d} E{\text{C}}=C,V{\text{C}},\text{d}V{\text{C}}$. Re-arrange their equation to find $\text{d} E{\text{C}}=C,V{\text{C}},\text{d}V{\text{C}}=\frac12,L,I{\text{L}}^2+\frac12,C,\left(\text{d}V{_\text{C}}\right)^2$. There's a Lagrangian here.
